# CMake Compiler not set

Tags: c++, cmake

CMake Error: CMAKE_Project_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage

I Get this Error after writing `cmake ..`

This is my CMakeLists.txt

````
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:/mingw64/bin/g++")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "C:/mingw64/bin/gcc")

project(CXX Project)

add_subdirectory(glfw/)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} Main.cpp)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC glfw)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC glfw)```


And this is my Complete Error
PS C:\Users\david\Documents\Idle\Project\build> cmake ..
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (project):
  Running

   'nmake' '-?'

  failed with:

   Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden


CMake Error: CMAKE_Project_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/david/Documents/Idle/Project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
````

Comment: Can you give the full error message?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but it's generally not a good idea to use the project root directory as the build directory. It's recommended to use a separate directory (`mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..`).

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to improve it (like adding crucial information or error messages).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using [the `project` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html) in the wrong way. It should be

```
project(Project CXX)
```

That's why CMake is looking for `CMAKE_Project_COMPILER` instead of `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in your error message `cmake` is trying to generate build files for `nmake`, the visual studio build system. What you are trying to setup is a `makefile` based build system with `mingw`. Therefore you should specify the generator directly:

```
cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"
```

Comment: The OP is on a Windows system. It's possible that the OP wants to use `nmake` to build.

Comment: I now have a new problem 
Here is the New [Error](https://pastebin.com/k24kgRzT)

Answer (score -1):

For "CMake Error: CMAKE_Project_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage"

Another possible problem is we need to execute cmake in e.g c:\users\xxx
and can't execute in c:\xxxx

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33883066)